# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error

Tags: python, list, int

I have a code that reads the info from a file (lines describe Points, Polygons, Lines and Circles) and parses it into according class. Point has x and 7 coordinates and Line has a starting point and an end point.

I have a list (`line = ['L1','L((1,1), (1,2))','# comment']`) and I try to make it into a line. The problem is with creating the end point, when executing I get the following error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` fr the variable `x2`

What is the problem?

Code:

```
def make_line(line):
        name = line[0]
        point = line[1].split(", ")
        p = point[0].split(",")
        x1 = int(p[0][3:])
        y1 = int(p[1][:-1])
        point1 = Point(x1,y1)
        p = point[1].split(",")
        x2 = int(p[0][1:])
        y2 = int(p[1][:-2])
        point2 = Point(x2,y2)
        line = Line(point1,point2)
        shapes[name] = line
```

Comment: Try printing out `p[0][1:]` to see if it is what you think it is. My gues is, you'll be surprised.

Comment: Are these part of the standard library?  What module can I get `Point` and `Line` from?

Comment: on the contrary! it prints out `1` but then when casting `int()` that's when the error occurs. @mrKelley, those are self-written classes

Comment: You have some capital `L`s in your input - is it possible that a lowercase `l` has crept in there, which is what you're seeing as a digit `1`?

Comment: Your code works for me with the example input when I remove the unrelated lines creating the `Point` and `Line` objects. `x2` is assigned the value 1.

Comment: So, are you sure that the error is being thrown in the casting and not the class?  With python3 I'm not getting any error from the code when I comment the instantiations of `Point` and `Line`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You error message says you are trying to convert an empty string to an int. Double check all your data immediately before doing the conversion to verify this.

It is an absolute certainty that if the data is correct, the cast to integer will work. Therefore, the only conclusion to be drawn is that your data is incorrect. You are claiming in comments to your question that the data is good, but that simply cannot be true.

Trust the python interpreter over your own assumptions.

Comment: I rechecked everything but couldn't find the mistake so I went on with testing my code but avoiding that faulty function. The lines fed to the function were read from a file. At some point I put that line in the end of file instead of middle of it and stuff works. "magic mystery bug fix" right there

Answer (score 0):

The error says there's something wrong with your code, but it does in fact run correctly.
If you ever get errors, it's worth finding the line where they occur, and using `print` to print their values to make absolutely sure you're passing the right values to the right methods.

An easy way to deal with this (at first glance) funny format is to use python's `eval()` function. You'll notice that the 2nd part of the list looks a lot like a set of two sets, and in fact it is.

If you do this, you'll get a nice set object out:

```
eval("((1,1), (1,2))")
# equivalent to this:
eval(line[1][1:],{}) # passing an empty dict as the 2nd argument makes eval a (bit) safer
```

but this is just a quick and dirty method, and should never be used in production code.

Comment: The code posted actually gives correct results, so your answer must be wrong. And recommending `eval` for parsing is horrible advice.

Comment: I'm aware `eval()` is not good practice, but I was demonstrating a quick and easy method to use. You're right I should have made its downsides clearer.
Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I removed the parts that you did not provide enough info about and I am still not getting the same error.

```
def make_line(line):
    name = line[0]
    point = line[1].split(", ")
    p = point[0].split(",")
    x1 = int(p[0][3:])
    y1 = int(p[1][:-1])
    p = point[1].split(",")
    x2 = int(p[0][1:])
    y2 = int(p[1][:-2])
    return x1, y1, x2, y2

>>> make_line(['L1','L((1,2), (1,1))','# comment'])
(1, 2, 1, 1)
```